# Why is Index view printing entire table?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, model-view-controller, erb

This app consists of a form to submit and currently I am trying to print a few rows of a table. This is working, but unfortunately I am also getting a single long string of the entire database table attributes. There is nothing in the code that I have written (I believe) which would cause this. I fear that this is some unseen rails magic, any insight would be great!

The controller:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  def create
     student_map = {"student_id" => params[:student_id], "student_name" => params[:student_name],
  "major" => params[:major], "minor" => params[:minor], "other_information" => params[:other_information], 
  "class_year_id" => params[:class_year_id], "hours_st" => params[:hours], "qr_id" => qr_id,}

     if (newStudentRow.save)
        redirect_to action: 'index'
     else
        render action: 'new'
     end
  end

  def index
     @students = Student.all
  end
end
```

The Index view:

```
<h1>Students#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/students/index.html.erb</p>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%= @students.each do |s| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= s.student_name %></td>
        <td><%= s.student_id %></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

After entering data and submitting the form, this link shows the following output:

[image: screen shot of output]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
<%= @students.each do |s| %>
```

To this:

```
<% @students.each do |s| %>
```

In Ruby, `each` executes the block for each element AND returns the array. Having the `=` outputs the array, which is why you are seeing that long string.